# storyboard.purgeScene() not working in exitScene, but it works when its on a function like tap

Tags: android, corona-storyboard

I'm new to android developing and would like to ask a simple question.

storyboard.purgeScene(sceneName) is not working in my scene:exitScene(e) but it works when I attach it to a tap function. Why is that so?

here is the sample code that is working right now:

```
local storyboard = require ( "storyboard" );
local scene = storyboard.newScene();

local startbtn;
local roller;
local ceiling;
local ground;
local leftwall;
local rightwall;

function scene:createScene(e)

local view = self.view;


local background = display.newImageRect( "background.png",  _W,  _H);
background.x = _W * 0.5;
background.y = _H * 0.5;

local logo = display.newImageRect( "logo.png",  800,  300);
logo.x = _W * 0.5;
logo.y = logo.height - 100;

startbtn = display.newImageRect( "start.png",  400,  150)
startbtn.x = _W * 0.5;
startbtn.y = logo.height + 150;

roller = display.newImageRect ( "roller.png", 150, 150 );
roller.x = _W * 0.5;
roller.y =  _H - 150;

ceiling = display.newImageRect( "horizontal.png",  _W,  50);
ceiling.x = _W * 0.5;
ceiling.y = 25;

ground = display.newImageRect( "horizontal.png",  _W,  50);
ground.x = _W * 0.5;
ground.y = _H - 25;

leftwall = display.newImageRect( "vertical.png",  50,  _H);
leftwall.x = 25;
leftwall.y = _H * 0.5;

rightwall = display.newImageRect( "vertical.png",  50,  _H);
rightwall.x = _W - 25;
rightwall.y = _H * 0.5;


view:insert(background);
view:insert(ceiling);
view:insert(ground);
view:insert(leftwall);
view:insert(rightwall);
view:insert(logo);
view:insert(startbtn);
view:insert(roller);




startbtn:addEventListener ( "tap", startbtn );

function startbtn:tap(e)
    storyboard.gotoScene("stage1");
    storyboard.purgeScene("menu");
end

 end


 function scene:enterScene(e)


physics.addBody ( roller, {density=10, friction=0.5, bounce=0.1, radius = 75});
physics.addBody ( ground, "static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );
physics.addBody ( ceiling,"static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );
physics.addBody ( leftwall, "static",{friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );
physics.addBody ( rightwall,"static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );


end


function scene:exitScene(e)

end


scene:addEventListener ( "createScene", scene );
scene:addEventListener ( "enterScene", scene );
scene:addEventListener ( "exitScene", scene );

return scene;
```

And here is the code that should be working but not.

```
storyboard = require ( "storyboard" );
local scene = storyboard.newScene();

local startbtn;
local roller;
local ceiling;
local ground;
local leftwall;
local rightwall;

function scene:createScene(e)

local view = self.view;


local background = display.newImageRect( "background.png",  _W,  _H);
background.x = _W * 0.5;
background.y = _H * 0.5;

local logo = display.newImageRect( "logo.png",  800,  300);
logo.x = _W * 0.5;
logo.y = logo.height - 100;

startbtn = display.newImageRect( "start.png",  400,  150)
startbtn.x = _W * 0.5;
startbtn.y = logo.height + 150;

roller = display.newImageRect ( "roller.png", 150, 150 );
roller.x = _W * 0.5;
roller.y =  _H - 150;

ceiling = display.newImageRect( "horizontal.png",  _W,  50);
ceiling.x = _W * 0.5;
ceiling.y = 25;

ground = display.newImageRect( "horizontal.png",  _W,  50);
ground.x = _W * 0.5;
ground.y = _H - 25;

leftwall = display.newImageRect( "vertical.png",  50,  _H);
leftwall.x = 25;
leftwall.y = _H * 0.5;

rightwall = display.newImageRect( "vertical.png",  50,  _H);
rightwall.x = _W - 25;
rightwall.y = _H * 0.5;


view:insert(background);
view:insert(ceiling);
view:insert(ground);
view:insert(leftwall);
view:insert(rightwall);
view:insert(logo);
view:insert(startbtn);
view:insert(roller);




startbtn:addEventListener ( "tap", startbtn );

function startbtn:tap(e)
    storyboard.gotoScene("stage1");
end

end


function scene:enterScene(e)


physics.addBody ( roller, {density=10, friction=0.5, bounce=0.1, radius = 75});
physics.addBody ( ground, "static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );
physics.addBody ( ceiling,"static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );
physics.addBody ( leftwall, "static",{friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );
physics.addBody ( rightwall,"static", {friction=0.5, bounce=0.1} );


end


function scene:exitScene(e)
storyboard.purgeScene("menu");
end


scene:addEventListener ( "createScene", scene );
scene:addEventListener ( "enterScene", scene );
scene:addEventListener ( "exitScene", scene );

return scene;
```

Can anyone explain this to me because I'm quite confused here.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, You got the your **function startbtn:tap(e)** inside you **createScene** function you have to move it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ,

-- scene1.lua
    local storyboard = require "storyboard"
    local scene = storyboard.newScene()

-- createScene event simply creates a background image
    function scene:createScene( event )
     local bg = display.newImage( self.view, "background.png" )
    end
    scene:addEventListener( "createScene" )

```
function scene:didExitScene( event )
 storyboard.purgeScene( "scene1" )
end
scene:addEventListener( "didExitScene" )
```

return scene

If you have more doubts check in :http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/31/storyboard-scene-purging-vs-removal/